# Terminal Command to run tests using GNU Parallel

Tags: terminal, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a folder of problems which are like this:

```
 problem1, domain 1
 problem2, domain 2
 problem3, domain 3
```

I want to use GNU Parallel to run a bunch of problems like this. This is short version of what I have tried:

```
 seq 01 20 | parallel -k -j6 java pddl/benchmarks_STRIPS/psr/p{}-domain.pddl -f pddl/benchmarks_STRIPS/psr/p{}.pddl
```

I want some sort of command that will tell GNU parallel that domain 1 is to be compiled with problem 1, domain 2 is with problem 2 etc.. 
Is there a way to do this using GNU or should I write each one out individually?

Comment: What's wrong with the current command you have?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Its not making the connection between domain 1 is to be used with problem 1 and then so on.. 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)' Thats the error I get but I can run it on its own like: 'psr/p01-domain.pddl -f psr/p01.pddl'

Comment: Does your `seq 01 20` produce zero-padded numbers? Mine doesn't. Maybe you need `printf "%02d\n" $(seq 1 20) | parallel ...`

Comment: Sorry! Its solved.. It was an issue with the parallel command. It was not taking in the zero correctly as the files are numbered 'p01' etc..

Comment: Yes I saw the issue as soon as you posted that.. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problems - good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks! You can add it as an answer and ill mark it correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be a problem with zero-padding, as my `seq` command doesn't zero-pad numbers.

If you have `bash 4+` (I think that's the correct version), you can use:

```
echo {01..20} | parallel ...
```

Or, if you have an older `bash`, you could use something like:

```
printf "%02d\n" {1..20} | parallel ...
```

Comment: The `echo {01..20} |` will only work if you set `-d ' '`. But you could instead do: `parallel ... ::: {01..20}`

Answer (score 1):

I assume the pXX-domain.pddl files exist. You can use GNU Parallel's `{= =}` syntax to compute the pXX name:

```
parallel -k -j6 java {}  -f '{= s/-domain(\.pddl)$/$1/ =}' ::: pddl/benchmarks_STRIPS/psr/p*-domain.pddl
```

Or if the opposite is true:

```
parallel -k -j6 java '{= s/(\.pddl)$/-domain$1/ =}' -f {} ::: pddl/benchmarks_STRIPS/psr/p??.pddl
```

Requires GNU Parallel 20140722.

This way you do not need to know in advance which files exist.